# Having trouble returning an async/await version of function that includes a .find and .map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to find out why async/await is not working with a function in my react app. The reason I am trying to do an async function is that I am getting an error on subsequent runs of this function. On initital render, it works find and returns an array. But afterwards, it returns an empty array.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getSwapPairs()
      .then((res) => {
        setSwapInfo(res.markets);
        setFromCurrencies(res.markets.map(item => item.quoteAsset));

        if (transactionType === 'BUY') {
          setSelectedCurrencyState({ ...selectedCurrencyState, selectedFromCurrency: localStorage.getItem('fromCurrency') || 'USD', selectedToCurrency: symbol || localStorage.getItem('toCurrency') });
        }
        setTransactionType(localStorage.getItem('transactionType', transactionType) || TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY);
      });
  }, []);

  const getBaseCurrencies = (fromCurrency) => {
    const filteredQuoteAssetObj = swapInfo.find(async item => item.quoteAsset === fromCurrency);
    const currencies = filteredQuoteAssetObj.baseAssets.map(async item => await item.baseAsset);
    return currencies;
  };
```

The argument being passed in is a state value that is being passed in so that the .find method can find a match. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt there is any asynchronous processes in your array that need to be awaited on. I am guessing that your issue is somewhere else. I am guessing you have a useEffect and setState somewhere? I have seen a-lot of times the useEffect accidentally clears the state on the next render thus an empty array. If you do think this is an async await issue, we will need to see what swapInfo is and why it needs to be awaited, but likely just add more of your other code so we can pin down the issue.

Comment: Hi Colin, you are correct. I have useEffect and setState. But not sure why it is doing that then. I will include it in my code.

Comment: "I am trying to find out why async/await is not working with a function in my react app" `array.find(async() => ...)` doesn't work, because an `async function` returns a Promise, which is an Object, which is a truthy value, this means that no matter what the Promise resolves to, `array.find(async() => ...)` will **always** find **the fist element** of the array.

Comment: I see. that makes sense. I will search for alternatives to accomplish this @Thomas

Comment: Just write `swapInfo.find(item => item.quoteAsset === fromCurrency)` and `filteredQuoteAssetObj.baseAssets.map(item => item.baseAsset)` without any `async`? What were you trying to wait for in the first place?